# Importing CSV as a point layer via the Python console. No point layer is loaded. How can I fix my code?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, csv, pyqgis-3

**Code**

```
import os
from qgis.core import (
    QgsVectorLayer
)

uri = r"file:\\\C:\Users\imper\Desktop\XYbuffer_tool\Calapan_XYpoints_comma?delimiter={}&crs=epsg:32651&xField={}&yField={}".format(",", "x_long", "y_lat")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "test", "delimited text")

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

From the PyQGIS documentaiton https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers

**Result**

No point layer is loaded

```
exec(open('C:/Users/imper/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpo4j1vq9h.py'.encode('utf-8')).read())
```

**CSV file**

> name,corner,x_long,y_lat Shell Calapan,1,121°12'07.5"E,13°25'42.6"N
>
> Shell Calapan,2,121°12'09.1"E,13°25'38.8"N  Shell
>
> Calapan,3,121°12'06.0"E,13°25'37.6"N Shell
>
> Calapan,4,121°12'04.3"E,13°25'41.5"N

Comment: Added QgsProject line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems. Firstly, you are specifying a UTM coordinate system (epsg:32651) in your `QgsDataSourceUri` string. The x and y fields of your csv file are clearly geographic coordinates! Try specifying epsg:4326 instead.

Secondly, because your x and y format is Degrees, Minutes and Seconds you must add an additional parameter to your uri string: `&xyDms=yes`.

Thirdly, you need forward slashes in your file path.

Fourthly, you must include the file extension (.csv) in the file path.

And finally, the last argument in your QgsVectorlayer constructor should be "delimitedtext" with no space.

So your code should look like:

```
uri = r"file:///C:/Users/imper/Desktop/XYbuffer_tool/Calapan_XYpoints_comma.csv?delimiter={}&crs=epsg:4326&xyDms=yes&xField={}&yField={}".format(",", "x_long", "y_lat")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "test", "delimitedtext")

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

When I recreated your csv and used the above code (adapted for my file path), I got the following result:

[image]

Comment: Copy! I should have added more instead of copying the code from the documentation. Thank you for the effort!

Comment: I have used the code but it is not working. It seems like that after the

`exec(open('C:/Users/imper/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp6ozao9lx.py'.encode('utf-8')).read())`

the `True` does not appear after

Comment: Added the `print` line but it's coming out as `False`. I'll just figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: @BallpenMan, double check your path, file name etc. I tested the code and it worked fine for me. The only change I made was the path to the csv on my machine.